# How can I configure Microsoft ADAM to be similar to Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adam

I want to put users into an instance of ADAM so that ADAM looks similar to a typical, real, Active Directory server.

I'm developing an application that integrates with LDAP.  I've tested with OpenLDAP and its core.schema.    Now I'd like to test with with Active Directory, but the closest I can get to that using my equipment is by testing with Microsoft ADAM.

I don't know exactly how to begin with ADAM.  Zero experience with it and Active Directory.  I'm guessing I need to import the MS-AdamSchemaW2K3.LDF because I see "sAMAccountName" in there, and I think I want that to be like Active Directory?

---

Added after reading a couple answers...

The answers so far aren't specific enough for what I'm looking for.  I did get ADAM to work and my app can talk to it, but what I want to do is to have ADAM working the way a typical (if there is such a thing) Active Directory installation would work, same schema, authentication, even though I'm just using ADAM in a workgroup network, on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

ADAM isn't really a complete replacement for Active Directory.  For example, ADAM doesn't understand different group types, and doesn't include a RootDSE by default.  You could test against ADAM but you may run into slight differences in your query structures.

If you are developing an application that will depend on Active Directory then you really should be building your application against an Active Directory.  I have been able to get several Domain Controllers running just fine in [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) (free) using only 300mb of memory and a [free evaluation version of Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/try-it.aspx).

If, however, you are building an application that simply needs an LDAP directory and isn't going to be using Active Directory than ADAM may work out just fine.  The schema extension file you mentioned (MS-AdamSchemaW2K3.LDF) would work just fine but you would want to setup RootDSE for easier binds.

Lastly, Microsoft AD/AM isn't really Admin friendly, especially in terms of troubleshooting.  [I ended up writing an application](http://www.dscoduc.com/post/2008/01/ADAM-Services-Debug.aspx) to help troubleshoot AD/AM issues that you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am only aware of importing MS-Users file. I see ther is a step-step guide

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5163b97a-7df3-4b41-954e-0f7c04893e83&DisplayLang=en

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by not being able to use your equipment to run an Active Directory instance instead of mucking around with ADAM.  I've run test AD servers in virtual machines with as little as 256 MB of RAM.  Seems to me that ADAM is never going to be an adequate test depending on what your doing.

I'd spend time trying to get an proper AD up and running instead.

Comment: I'm doing this at home.  It's not my day job.  At home, I have Windows XP Pro.  I don't have Windows Server 20003, etc.

Comment: You can run a test Windows Server on top of XP Pro using VMWare they have a free VMWare Server product you can install or a trial of VMWare workstation.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to install Windows 2003 server with Active Directory loaded as a domain controller. You cannot 100% duplicate AD characteristics using ADAM alone.